# how to implement qt Virtual keyboard in qt desktop application without using Qt Quick

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I want to work on application that should give me mobile device look but the application will run on linux based device.
I need access to port which I have checked creating qt application ,now with use of this i want to create UI to be run on linux touch device.
i have experience on qt of about 7 month i have most of the basic knowldege of qt , but now i want to go in detail and advance.
so need help and idea what i should install to add mobile device look in qt application without qt quick.
which version will be best. 
how i can add virtual keyboard in application.

the idea is to develop a qt application with mobile look and feel along with communication with hardwares.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [VirtualKeyboard](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php?content=107388). It's a virtual keyboard for touch-screen applications. It would compile normally with Qt 4 and 5.

As stated in [Alternatives for Virtual Keyboards](http://www.ics.com/blog/alternatives-virtual-keyboards) one other option is to use [Maliit](https://gitorious.org/maliit/). It works with both widgets and QML and supports Qt 4 and 5.

Finally a search on google or browsing [qt-apps.org](http://qt-apps.org) would give you some results.